# How to view images on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gnome

I have images that I am generating and need to be able to view.  Is there a way to view the images I have saved on my EC2 instance without scp'ing them over every time I regenerate them?

I tried using `eog` but I got the following error:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(eog:15870): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Run an HTTP server there. Note that they must pass the net to be seen :)

Comment: Is this getting down voted because there isn't a simple solution?  It's a legitimate problem and I'm not sure how to solve it

Comment: No idea on negative votes, may be it was that clear to down voters that they don't spend time explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PyCharm professional to sync with the remote server.  It let me browse the file system and view images and works with my Mac.